# Making default font size 16pt

Tags: fontsize

I want to write a document which has the default font size as 16pt. But I believe `\documentclass[a4paper,16pt]{report}` will not do it. What will be the correct way to make the default font size as 16 pt

Comment: As the answers to this question complement the ones to the linked question, this question should rather be merged with (i.e., its answers transferred to) question 5339 than simply closed as a duplicate.