# How can I define my font size?

Tags: fontsize

According to [LyX Wiki](http://wiki.lyx.org/FAQ/ChangeFontUsingLatex), I can define my font size by means of this code (in case of 10.5pt) :

```
\usepackage{type1cm}

\renewcommand\normalsize{%
   \@setfontsize\normalsize{10.5pt}{12pt}
   \abovedisplayskip 10\p@ \@plus2\p@ \@minus5\p@
   \abovedisplayshortskip \z@ \@plus3\p@
   \belowdisplayshortskip 6\p@ \@plus3\p@ \@minus3\p@
   \belowdisplayskip \abovedisplayskip
   \let\@listi\@listI}\normalsize
```

But how can I calculate this value in case of 14pt, 16pt, 18pt?

Comment: do you want to have a document wide normal fontsize of 14pt?

Comment: No; my normal my normal fontsize is 12pt; but the fontsize of : section(18pt); susection(16pt); subsubsection(14pt) ;

Answer (score 6):

Note that defining the font size manually like this is not the normal way to do it and only for advanced users. You should use a package or class for changing the font size globally. If you simply want a larger font use `\large`, `\Large`, `\LARGE`, `\huge`, or `\Huge`. With LaTeX it is not common to specify the font size of a piece of text in points.

You can set the default (global) font size by using the `10pt`, `11pt` or `12pt` class options. For more font sizes see the following threads:
[Making default font size 16pt](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30693/making-default-font-size-16pt)
[How to specify font size less than 10pt (or more than 12pt)?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5339/how-to-specify-font-size-less-than-10pt)

Comment: Thank you Martin; i have a thesis with the following font size specification   : textsize(12pt); section(18pt); susection(16pt); subsubsection(14pt) ; how i get it?

Answer (score 3):

If the normal fontsize is 12pt, you can redefine the section headers:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\section{\@startsection {section}{1}{\z@}%
                                   {-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                                   {2.3ex \@plus.2ex}%
                                   {\normalfont\fontsize{18pt}{19pt}\selectfont\bfseries}}
\renewcommand\subsection{\@startsection{subsection}{2}{\z@}%
                                     {-3.25ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                                     {1.5ex \@plus .2ex}%
                                     {\normalfont\fontsize{16pt}{17pt}\selectfont\bfseries}}
\renewcommand\subsubsection{\@startsection{subsubsection}{3}{\z@}%
                                     {-3.25ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                                     {1.5ex \@plus .2ex}%
                                     {\normalfont\fontsize{14pt}{15pt}\selectfont\bfseries}}
\makeatother
```

Comment: Is there really no easier way that using `\@startsection`?

Comment: if you want the old behaviour of `\large` et al then there is no other way. However, it is not a big deal to redefine that commands or using package `titlesec` which does the same

Answer (score 2):

You could have a look at the [`.clo` files of LaTeX](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/unpacked) (`size*.clo`, `bk*.clo`) and at the `.clo` files of [`extsizes`](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/extsizes).

For example, from `size14.clo` of `extsizes`:

```
\renewcommand\normalsize{%
   \@setfontsize\normalsize\@xivpt{17}%
   \abovedisplayskip 14\p@ \@plus3\p@ \@minus7\p@
   \abovedisplayshortskip \z@ \@plus4\p@
   \belowdisplayshortskip 7\p@ \@plus4\p@ \@minus3\p@
   \belowdisplayskip \abovedisplayskip
   \let\@listi\@listI}
```

Answer (score 1):

The koma-script classes have an option `fontsize` that can take any value; `fontsize=14pt` should do what you want.