# How do I format the whole document in sans-serif?

Tags: fonts, sans-serif

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Simplest way to typeset entire document in sans serif (Helvetica)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2095/simplest-way-to-typeset-entire-document-in-sans-serif-helvetica)

I'd like to have all the font in my document to be sans-serif, i.e.:

```
\textsf{}
```

What is the best and easiest way to set this globally?

Thanks,

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). I think you can have a look to [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/62752/mimic-beamer-font-in-article-mode#62755).

Comment: Also of interest: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2095/simplest-way-to-typeset-entire-document-in-sans-serif-helvetica

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has worked well for me in the past.

```
% Helvet font throughout
\usepackage{helvet}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
```