# How to change default font size with XeLaTeX compiler and style file

Tags: xetex, fontsize

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Making default font size 16pt](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30693/making-default-font-size-16pt)

I need to change font size to 14 points with XeLaTeX. I used:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 14pt]{report}
```

But the result is still `10pt`. I checked `.sty` file, nothing there is specified.

Can someone help me on it?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/5764) You don't have to sign with your name since [it automatically appears in the lower right corner](http://tex.stackexchange.com/faq#signatures) of your post.

Comment: The default font sizes under `report` is `10pt`, `11pt` and `12pt`. A different class would work, as in the linked post.

Comment: I'by can't figure out by what you term "I checked `.sty` file". Do you mean the .log file?