# Default font size to 13pt?

Tags: fontsize

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Making default font size 16pt](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30693/making-default-font-size-16pt)

I have this header:

```
\documentclass[12pt,italian,a4paper,oneside,openright]{book}
```

When ever i try 13pt or greater i only get smaller font in my paper.

Is there any way to get 13pt font size?

My definition is:

```
\documentclass[12pt,italian,a4paper,oneside,openright]{book}
\usepackage{url,amsfonts,epsfig}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{vmargin}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

Comment: Have a look at my answer to the linked question describing the `scrextend` package.

Comment: I'd also remark that `epsfig` is an obsolete package whose commands should not be used in new documents. Rather than `vmargin` I suggest `geometry`: `vmargin` is incompatible with `pdfpages` and other packages.