# Setting default font size to 13pt

Tags: fontsize

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to specify font size less than 10pt (or more than 12pt)?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5339/how-to-specify-font-size-less-than-10pt-or-more-than-12pt)

Many questions in this matter has been posted and most of the answers are related to either using `KOMA-script` class or using XeTeX, or using the `\documentclass{extreport}` which doesn't have a 13pt. So if a report class with default font size of 13pt is required, what should I do?

Comment: There's no need to use a `KOMA-Script` *class* -- using the `scrextend` package will do. See my [answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/30699/510) to http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30693/making-default-font-size-16pt

Comment: You can also put `\fontsize{13}{15.6}\selectfont` where `13pt` is the font size and `15.6pt` is the baseline skip (which is nearly 120% of fontsize). But you have to use proper fonts that can be scaled.

Comment: By the way, [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: @HarishKumar I guess the OP wants to affect all font-switching commands, as a class option like `12pt´ would do.

Comment: @lockstep: Putting it in preamble will do it... or not? :)

Comment: @HarishKumar You'll affect one font switching command at most ... or not?

Comment: The above mentioned methods by @lockstep, doesn't actually produce 13pt font size but the size remain 12pt. The suggested methods don't have 13pt as default so they fallback to 12pt!.

Comment: @lockstep ..:-)

Comment: @AshishZachariah I'm sorry, but there was one crucial piece of information missing (also in my answer): Make sure to use a scalable font, e.g. with `\usepackage{lmodern}`.